# скрипт аудиоплеера инициализируется дважды

Tags: инициализация, плеер

Коллеги. Проблема в следующем.

Есть **муз.сайт**.

1. Однокнопочный плеер слева от каждой песни. Всё отлично воспроизводится.
2. Есть кнопка "Загрузить ещё песни". **Посредством аякса подгружаются ещё 20 песен**.
3. Если начать воспроизводить песню с нового подгруженного блока, будут воспроизводиться **две песни одновременно**, хотя та, которая играла, должна останавливаться.
4. Если всё остановить и опять включить песню - **она начнёт играть дважды**, т.е. например "ве-ве-тер с мо-мо-ря-ря ду-дул, на-на-гоня-нял бе-бе-ду-дуу".
5. Потом если подгрузить ещё 20 песен, плеер инициализируется ещё раз и песня будет воспроизводиться три раза одновременно!

Прослушка становится невозможной! Одна и та же песня накладывается сама на себя несколько раз.

Прошу помощи разобраться. Как укротить этот скрипт? Плеер называется **ubaPlayer**
Прикладываю скриншот кода. Основные моменты прокомментировал
[image: скриншот]

Comment: На скриншоте видно, что вы действительно инициализируете плеер каждый раз после загрузки контента, вот в этой строке $("#ubaplayer").ubaPlayer(...). Возможно поможет унести это выше (до клика), или тогда плеер не проигрывает треки?

Comment: Пробовал переносить. Во всех случаях ругается, что путь к файлу не найден. Там просто данные не подгружаются - приходят пустые данные. Вне скрипта, в основной странице в коде, плеер уже инициализиурется. Здесь он запускается второй раз. Если здесь его не прописать, при нажатии на плеер, страница вообще перезагружается, при этом в консоли никаких записей нет.